# Source of Greek long alpha

Tags: historical-linguistics, greek

I'm reading about the Greek first declension on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_nouns), which mentions that the origin of the first declension originally had long alpha, which then shifted to eta, except when after rho, iota, and epsilon. However, looking at the example [declension table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%86%CF%89%CE%BD%CE%AE#Ancient_Greek), in the accusative plural case it shows the long alpha despite not being among the exceptions. I'm guessing that this is due to loss of `n` lengthening the vowel. Is this true, and are there other examples/counterexamples?

Comment: You mean the accusative _plural_ here? That is indeed due to the loss of /n/. It also appears in the accusative (and nominative/vocative) _dual_, of course, where it has a different origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is due to the loss of a nasal: -ans > -ās. The vowel becoming longer when a following consonant disappears is called "compensatory lengthening" and is especially common in Ancient Greek. (cf *es-mi > ειμί eimí "I am".)

In the Lesbian Aeolic dialect, the result of compensatory lengthening is not ā but ai, which provides a nice way to check this: Lesbian first-declension nouns have -ās in the nominative singular but -ais in the accusative plural.

Comment: AFAIK the αι reflex is only Lesbian, not general Aeolic, and *Aeolic first-declension nouns have -ās in the nominative singular* is true only of masculines.

Comment: @vectory would `cf εἰμί eimí /e:mí/ < PIE *h₁és-mi` satisfy you?

Comment: @vectory I don't always have a polytonic Greek keyboard available, so I assumed anyone working with Greek would recognize that eimi was a transliteration of the extremely common word ειμι. Added that to the answer now.

Comment: @vectory oh, in that case you're just wrong https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cf

Comment: Well, in comparativistic, where *cp.* has a dedicated meaning, you cannot use *cf* 3. "written abbreviation for compare" unless it's to a book. 1. "used in writing when you want the reader to make a comparison between the subject being discussed and something else" is applicable, indeed, but it is the least specific. Cf I said "Please be more precise".

Comment: @vectory I'm really not sure how this has any impact on the answer, but cf is short for _confer_, the Latin Imperative of _conferre_ "bring together for comparison". I'm instructing the reader to take the changes in \*-ans > -ās and set them next to the changes in \*esmi > eimi to see the similarity. This is the only meaning of "cf" that makes sense in context.

Comment: Oh and I'd have thunk *conferre* was from *fōr* "speak". Such cases ^_^

Comment: @vectory The starred forms are not Proto-Indo-European but some stage of Proto-Hellenic.